# How did the birds come back to life when Envy arrived?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

After Cornello had been eaten by Gluttony, the townspeople search for him but find a lot of dead birds. Envy arrives as Cornello and passes off a miracle and claims that the Cornello who had been "conning" everyone was sent by the devil while "he" was out of town. The miracle he performs is bringing the birds back to life, but out of everyone's view in the sky the birds explode.

Now I can understand how it's possible if alchemy was used, however, none the homunculi can use Alchemy except for Wrath, because:

> His arm and leg belong to Ed, and as such can create an array with them since "the truth" was engraved into Ed's body and he had only lost one limb at that time.

So I am wondering, how did those birds come back to life?

EDIT: I'm referring to the original (first produced).

Comment: This is an odd one. On one hand, it seems like a plot hole, as Envy's ability only allows himself to change form. On the other hand, there was no transmutation light, and the bird that the real Cornello transmuted did not explode.

Comment: @Eric i can assume that it was all staged and the birds was prepared by the homunculi and placed in clear sight for the people of Lior to find ready for Envy's performance but you have a point, when Cornello used the false stone the bird be brought back to life was alive for quite a while so it also begs the question if a false stone was ever used (still, who would use it, the homunculi can't use it anyway)

Comment: The only thing I can think is that the birds are a detached part of Envy's body and he can control them for a short period before they die, hence the explosions. But I have nothing to back this up as of now.

Comment: Please claim firstly, which series you are talking about: Brotherhood, or the original one?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt it's the original one, i've edited the the question to indicate it

Comment: This question is probably one of those questions that will never be answered unless you will accept an interview that says it was a production mistake (not that I have one though).

Comment: @アズーサ i'd be more than happy to accept that if the source is cited

Answer (score 3):

Envy has the ability to transform its body into whatever form. BUT, its original form was that which resembles a lizard with a mane made out of the souls which were inside its Stone. **(Reference: Manga)** Each philosopher stone contains a countless amount of souls. The only logical explanation is that it cut one of those souls off and made it into a bird. But souls that are cut from the main body cannot exist for long ((Similar to when a Homunculus's arm is cut off, the arm disappears but a new one is regenerated) otherwise the world would be filled with infinite number of severed, unidentified limbs...)

Being that Envy's true form is that of an animal, this also mean that it can transform itself into animal. Envy can also make its arms into things like swords or other shard blunt objects. (Weapons)

*This question might also be something unanswerable, because...*

The original FMA did NOT follow the manga. I will say it again. **DID NOT FOLLOW THE MANGA**. So basically after the Elric brother's mom died, the director metaphorically walks off the side walk across the street and at times in the middle of the road, but most of the time he's swimming in the river next to the side walk.

So it's not that hard to believe that this might just be something completely thought up in the moment in order to fill a gap in the story. FMA:BH follows the Manga.

Comment: Actually, certain parts of the original anime follow the manga *more closely* than *Brotherhood* does.

Comment: Yes that would be when he's walking back on the side walk.

Comment: I'm just pointing out when you say, "FMA:BH follows the Manga," that's not fully true. In general, particularly later in the series, it does, but not always.

Comment: I guess it's just assumed on my part that this would be common sense. But you are correct. Thank you for clarifying this for those who have not read the Manga.

Comment: @BizzMizz: this would have been my interpretation had 2003 followed the manga continuity's conception of Envy, but it still makes sense.